# A bash function definition that doesn't seem to work

Tags: bash, ls

I was experimenting with shell functions the other day, with the objective of overriding the `ls` command.
The intention was to have the shell call my `ls` function first then if the first switch is "-y" do one thing, otherwise call the regular `/bin/ls`, but the result behaves in a way I don't understand.

To enable it I decided to use "-y" for the switch because:

```
$ ls -y
ls: invalid option -- 'y'
Try `ls --help' for more information.
```

So it can't break the core functionality of `ls`.
Anyway, reducing the problem to its simplest, and with a couple of other examples to help highlight the problem:

```
$ function ls() { [[ "y$1" == "y-y" ]] && echo LS ; } 
$ function less() { [[ "y$1" == "y-y" ]] && echo LESS ; }
$ function try() { [[ "y$1" == "y-y" ]] && echo TRY ; }
```

So I'm overriding `ls`, `less` and defining `try` which is like the "contol" specimen :)

Now Invoking this way:

```
$ ls ; less ; try
```

It behaves as expected (no output), but:

```
$ ls -y ; less -y ; try -y
LESS
TRY
```

the `ls` fails to work, but the `less` override does, as does the "control".

Elsewhere on stackoverflow or askubuntu (but I've lost the reference for the minute) I saw an example  that implied `ls` was a builltin, but:

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

and:

```
$ builtin ls
bash: builtin: ls: not a shell builtin
```

So it doesn't seem to be on my system (and even if it was I can't actually see why it would behave like this).

I wonder what the explanation is? It isn't important, but I'd like to understand what's going on.

Thanks.

Comment: After reading the answers I've decided to add this comment: "Doh!"

Comment: You mean you didn't recall instantly the half-dozen ways the command you type isn't the command that executes? newb! ;)

Comment: “Smile when you call me that." :)

Comment: I think what happened was I fixated on the "builtin" thing to the exclusion of any other explanation, even though it couldn't actually explain anything. "When the problem isn't where you're looking, it's somewhere else!" Repeat 100 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `which`, use `type`. If you have something like

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
```

Then your function will fail in an interactive shell. Remove this in your `.bashrc` or wherever its defined. You can also use the `unalias` builtin.

You also need to avoid recursion if running a command of the same name as a function within a function.

```
ls()
    if [[ $1 == -y ]]; then
        shift
        ...
    else
        command ls "$@"
    fi
```

Also, make sure you know what you're doing if you decide to define functions using the `function` keyword. Use POSIX-style `funcname() compound-command` when you need POSIX compatibility as of this writing.

Comment: @msw `type` is nice. I'd say it's preferred when targeting Bash. Unfortunately POSIX says almost nothing about what it's actually supposed to do, so the options and exact output varies substantially.

Comment: thanks ormaaj. (My "real" version had a check for recursion: this was just a reduction to the simplest case).

Answer (score 5):

It is common to setup an alias for `ls`, which may be the case for you. Aliases are processed first, which is simple substitution of text. What happens in your example is:

```
A) `ls` is replaced with `ls --color=auto` 
B) Your `ls` function is called with the replaced text and your -y option 
C) Your function checks "$1", which is --color=auto
```

Below shows an example of this behavior:

```
$ function ls() { [[ "y$1" == "y-y" ]] && echo LS ; }
$ ls -y
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
$ unalias ls
$ type ls
ls is a function
ls ()
{
    [[ "y$1" == "y-y" ]] && echo LS
}
$ function ls() { [[ "y$1" == "y-y" ]] && echo LS ; }
$ ls -y
LS
$ alias ls="ls --color=auto"
$ ls -y
--color=auto -y
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that

```
$ alias ls
```

will show you the cause.